# copy/paste of Page doesn't start workflow in same SG, starts workflow in other SG

Tags: tridion

I was perplexed by a user turning up this sort of behavior recently. Assume all SGs have workflow set.

Copy Page X in SG A, paste in same SG A. Page Y is created but no workflow is initiated.
Copy Page X in SG A, paste in other SG B. Page Z is created and workflow is initiated.

Now, the first scenario I confirmed with Nuno when he was on site. We agreed with business folks that we can live with that behavior. However, I'm curious why the second scenario happens as-is. If #1 doesn't kick off workflow, why should #2? Can anyone explain why? Is there any way I could programmatically cause scenario #1 to start the workflow (as the business would like that to happen)? or, worst case disable it from #2. It should be consistent.

Comment: I'd submit a support ticket for this.  The behavior is odd and could be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tried this on my system, and it does not start a workflow in any case (copy/pasting to same structure group or different structure group).

Do you have an event triggered on Paste?

Comment: going to explore that... support can't duplicate either. so, I'm exploring what may be causing it. will update when I have more insight.

Comment: sorry. forgot to post this before going on vacation. apparently this has to do with the custom Navigation code we have in place. in my environment without Navigation, it doesn't start workflow at all. We'll work with the team that developed Navigation to fix that so it's consistent in not starting the workflow. if we can't talk business folks out of it, we'll consider Ram G's code to start the workflow if they require it.

Comment: I was afraid it was that one, since starting workflow on paste (under some conditions) is one of the requirements for the navigation...

Answer (score 1):

But in practical scenario, I would really question the need for workflow to kick off as soon as you copy the page in the same structure group.

When you copy a page in the same structure group, it will create a page with title `Copy of original page name` and the CMS User will obviously wants/needs to edit the page with proper page name. As soon as they save the page workflow kicks in. Also, CMS user may want to change some component presentations on the page as well.

When you copy this on a different structure group, you are creating a page with a name in other structure group, so the workflow kicks in since it is not same copy in same structure group.

I would consider this as a nice feature :) :).

However as Nick suggested I would recommend submitting a support ticket as well.

If you want to consider a programmatic approach for your scenario # 1, you could implement the EventSystem to force the workflow kick off by simply saving the page again with same user who created it. You need to capture the `CopyEvent` .

Sample EventSystem stub if you want to go this route (Not Tested) :

```
private void Subscribe()
{
     EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, CopyEventArgs>(PostCopyActivity, EventPhases.Processed);
}

private static void PostCopyActivity(Page page, CopyEventArgs args, EventPhases phase) 
{
    // do your logic to save page..
       string sourceId = args.CopiedObject.OrganizationalItem.Id;
       string destinationId = args.Destination.ToString();
       if (sourceId.Equals(destinationId))
       {
          // copying to the same location .. so now get the User Session and Update the page to force workflow

       }
}
```

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Please note that the event should be CopyEvent. Will update my post.

Comment: thanks. I will explore that code to help make the business happy. the rules here is that all content goes through workflow and publishing only happens through workflow. So, if the workflow doesn't start when someone creates/edits a page (which they consider copy/paste a page creation) then that causes confusion for the authors. Will confirm your code works, hopefully soon :)